# Rust struct field is function pointer with return

Tags: rust, syntax

How can I specify a struct field that takes a function with a certain signature, including a return type?

Here's the gist of what I have:

```rust
struct State {
    transition: &'static fn(char) -> u8, 
    // More fields...
}

fn main() {
    let state_a = State{
        transition: |c: char| {
            // do stuff
            1
        },
        // other fields...
    };
}
```

But despite the `-> u8` in the struct field, I'm getting a syntax error like this:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:125:35
    |
125 |                                   1
    |             ----------------------^--
    |             |                     |
    |             |                     expected `()`, found integer
    |             expected this to be `()`
```

I'm a little new to rust, so I think I might just be missing a bit of syntax here. I feel like it's something little or obvious, but I'm just missing it. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transition` doesn't need to be a static reference if it owns the clousure as in your sample code.

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c126a30b3f3cbd4c55fe80ea421f1a5b)

```
struct State {
    transition: fn(char) -> u8, 
    // More fields...
}

fn main() {
    let state_a = State{
        transition: |c: char| -> u8 {
            // do stuff
            1
        },
        // other fields...
    };
    
    println!("Transition: {}", (state_a.transition)('c'));
}
```

[Rust can also infer the types for Closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#closure-type-inference-and-annotation), so following would work too.

```
struct State {
    transition: fn(char) -> u8, 
    // More fields...
}

fn main() {
    let state_a = State{
        transition: |c: char| {
            // do stuff
            1
        },
        // other fields...
    };
    
    println!("Transition: {}", (state_a.transition)('c'));
}
```

Comment: The return type of the lambda will be inferred, it does not default to unit---see, e.g., https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=34653e6baff0c5b86e589188c2c10e5b

Comment: Dropping the borrow and adding the return helped, thank you! :)

Comment: Thanks for correcting kopecs! I was thinking from the context of OP's error message and the general behaviour of a function without explicit `->`. But you're correct in this context of the question, and I have included a link from the book where it shows types are inferred for closures.

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce the error you show. Instead, I get

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:8:21
   |
8  |           transition: |c: char| {
   |  _____________________^
9  | |             // do stuff
10 | |             1
11 | |         },
   | |_________^ expected `&fn(char) -> u8`, found closure
   |
   = note: expected reference `&'static fn(char) -> u8`
                found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:8:21: 11:10]`
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3083424f1055e5874b6e4717b0fc15b))

which would be expected given you're trying to use a closure as if it were a *reference* to a [function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/function-pointer.html). [Using a closure as if it were a function pointer itself is permitted, given the closure doesn't capture anything](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html#call-traits-and-coercions), but that isn't quite what you're doing here. You either need to obtain a reference to the closure (and also explicitly cast to achieve the required closure to `fn(char) -> u8` coercion):

```rs
        transition: &((|c: char| {
            // do stuff
            1
        }) as fn(_) -> _),
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44ed3e742f021f655b461c89c1291dc1))

or, the simpler option, just drop the unnecessary borrow from the type:

```
struct State {
    transition: fn(char) -> u8, 
    // More fields...
}

fn main() {
    let state_a = State{
        transition: |c: char| {
            // do stuff
            1
        },
        // other fields...
    };
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4f1536a58c62cffe0a1c8722dae8b7b1))

Comment: Oops, yup, I should have not borrowed. I thought I still had the return type error even without it, but maybe I was mistaken. I was tweaking things a bunch while I was debugging and writing the question.